telethon send_read_acknowledge doesn't work for megagroup
I have some function for marking archived dialogs as read in my telegram account, but it doesn't work if this dialog is megagroup. I suspect there is no way to do it, if it not, please help me
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
async def mark_archived_dialogs_as_read(event):
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs(archived=True):
        if event.message.message == dialog.message.message:
            if isinstance(event.peer_id, types.PeerChat):
                await client.send_read_acknowledge(entity=await client.get_entity(dialog.name),
                                                   max_id=event.message.id,
                                                   clear_mentions=True,
                                                   clear_reactions=True,
                                                   )
            elif isinstance(event.peer_id, types.PeerChannel):
                entity = await client.get_entity(dialog.name)
                if entity.megagroup:
                    await client.send_read_acknowledge(entity=entity,
                                                       max_id=event.message.id,
                                                       clear_mentions=True,
                                                       clear_reactions=True,
                                                       )
                else:
                    await client.send_read_acknowledge(entity=entity,
                                                       max_id=event.message.id,
                                                       clear_mentions=True,
                                                       clear_reactions=True,
                                                       )


My function can see any message in megagroups, but what haven't I tried it doesn't work

Please share any error message if you have.

There is no error message, it just doesn’t work, messages don’t mark as read

@chachatonel-hashimotto my answer to your question is on top
